# Error java.lang.NullPointerException in JSON parsing

Tags: java, json

I am new to Java,and using below code to parse JSON,but I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException error when the offers {} node is coming with empty values ,which is public class in my code.

How to handle empty JSON nodes/keys ??

The code is able to parse JSON if there is data under "offers" like "info",but exiting with NULL exception error when JSON returns and empty  as shown below.

**ERROR MSG :**

```
Exception in thread "api_temp_1.dat" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.t.dw.dl.api.data.Pkg_Data.getCount(Pkg_Data.java:57)
at com.t.dw.dl.api.DataRetrieveRunnable.run(DataRetrieveRunnable.java:185)
```

**Code extracts from error lines shown**

```
public long getCount() {
        if (offers != null)
          return offers.getPkg().size();
        return 0;
      }

    **Code from com.t.dw.dl.api.DataRetrieveRunnable.run(DataRetrieveRunnable.java:185)**
          try
          {
            Pkg_Data dls = parseResult(result);
            if (dls.getCount() > 0)
            {
              fw.write(deals.writeResults(fields, delimiter));
              threadStats.increment(Stats2.COUNT_OF_ROWS_PROCESSED,
                  dls.getCount());
            }
          }

    Parsing code:
      private Pkg_Data parseResult( String result ) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jo = parser.parse(result);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Pkg_Data ehw = gson.fromJson(jo, Pkg_Data.class);
        return ehw;
      }
```

**CODE:**

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

public class offers
{
  private ArrayList<PkgData> pkg;

  class Pkgdata
  {
    Info Info;

    class Info
    {
      String Id;
      String Url;

    }
    public String getId() {
      if (Info != null && Info.Id != null)
        return Info.Id;
      return "";
    }
```

**SAMPLE JSON: NOT working for this where "offers" returns empty**

```
{  
       "offerInfo":{  
          "siteID":"1",
          "language":"en_US",
          "currency":"USD"
       },
       "offers":{ }
        }
```

Comment: Are using classes in package "javax.json" ?

Comment: Give us the stack trace, it may help resolving this faster

Comment: @VVJ ,Not sure as I am pretty new to the Java & trying to modify an existing code ,but I can see GSON package being used.

Comment: @Phantomazi,I have added the error I am getting ,I think it's same as stack trace.

Comment: I don't see the code that is causing the exception. `com.t.dw.dl.api.data.Pkg_Data.getCount`

Comment: @markbernard,I have added the code in com.t.dw.dl.api.data.Pkg_Data.getCount

Comment: There is not enough code to make a determination. I assume `offers.getPkg()` returns the ArrayList and it looks like it is null. Show ALL the relevant code. The code that is parsing the JSON is not there either. Also where is the JSON coming from? That could be empty.

Comment: @rkj don't forget there is a difference between being null and being empty.

Comment: @markbernard,The code works perfectly while the JSON response has all data under <offers> like <info> but throwing error if the <offers> is empty.I have also added the parsing logic used

Comment: I think is that is because offer dont have any value init and because its not having a value its showing error.

Answer (score 0):

That is because offer is compared to the Class that you giving to refer so in that case Json will be wrong try with this Json it will work.

```
{
  "offerInfo": {
    "siteID": "1",
    "language": "en_US",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  "offers": {
    "siteID": " ",
    "language": "",
    "currency": " "
  }
}
```

Because Compiler not able to find any field attribute in side your offer object so its giving error.

try this Json.

Comment: I need to handle the case where JSON returns empty ,so I need to make changes to the code to handle that scenario.

Comment: then u should not parse as that class object if u do then it will create exception and but u can handle it before parsing.